# jQuery Table sorter row duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Currently, I am trying to use the jQuery table sorter plugin to sort my table rows. Current, my table data will be updated every 60 seconds, so if i start to sort before the 60 seconds it works normal, but after the 60 seconds if i try to sort my table rows get duplicated. Can I know whats the reason and how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($(".tablesorter").find('tbody:first tr').length > 0){
            $(".tablesorter").tablesorter(); 
            $(".tablesorter").trigger('update'); 
            alert("success");
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: How your table is updating every 60 sec?, you should call trigger('update') there.

Comment: actually i am using `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);` for my table to update every 60 seonds, its a separate function

Comment: $(".tablesorter").trigger('update'), you should add this code in that method after table is updated with new data.

Comment: should i add the code below the setTimeout function or above of it?

Comment: Please add that method as well in question for clarity. trigger update call should be called after the table updated with new data.

Comment: but why after several times sorting after that my whole js function crashes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `setTimeout` to update tablesorter, update tablesorter *after* whatever ajax function adds or removes content from the table. Something like this:

```
// tablesorter initialized outside of the ajax process
$("table").tablesorter();

$.ajax("load-new-stuff.php")
  .done(function(data) {
    // process the data and add it to the table
    addData(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    $("table tbody").html("<tr><td colspan='5'>Error</td></tr>");
  })
  .always(function() {
    $("table").trigger("update");
  });
```